# Why does the variable print correctly in one part of the program but not another

Tags: c

What is the error in my program? This is the code:

```
/*
 * courseProject.c
 *
 * It is a simple database for record shop
 * to track its iventory of CDs
 *
 * by Mahmoud Emam, 2012.
 */
#include<stdio.h>

main()
{
      /*
       * CDs infrormations
       */
      char title[31], artist[31];
      short int numberOfTracks;  /* short to save memory */
      int albumOrSingle;         /* Boolean to check 1 for Album and 0 for Single */
      float price;

      printf("Hello, Welcome to Record Shop!\n\n");
      /*
       * Asking for CD details
       */
      printf("Enter CD details\n\n");
      printf("CD's Title: ");
      scanf("%[^\n]", title);
      fflush(stdin);

      printf("CD's Artist: ");
      scanf("%[^\n]", artist);


      printf("Number of tracks: ");
      scanf("%d", &numberOfTracks);


      printf("Please press \"1\" for album, \"0\" for single: ");
      scanf("%d", &albumOrSingle);


      printf("CD's Price: ");
      scanf("%f", &price);

      /*
       * Output CD details
       */
      printf("\nCD details:\n");
      printf("=============\n\n");

      printf("CD's Title: <%s>\n", title);
      printf("CD's Artist: <%s>\n", artist);
      printf("Number of tracks: <%d>\n", numberOfTracks);

      if (albumOrSingle)
         printf("This is <Album>\n");
      else
         printf("This is <Single CD>\n");

      printf("Its price = <%.2f>\n", price);
      printf("=============\n\n");

      /* Exit from program */
      printf("Press any key to exit\n");

      fflush(stdin);
      getchar();
}
```

This is a simple program that reads CD info from the user and outputs the details again on the screen. However, the `artist` variable is always empty. Why?

I made `printf("%s", artist);` after I read it from the user and it works correctly, but it doesn't work at the end of the program. The variable is always empty.

Comment: Probably better for [codereview.SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com), this isn't a find the problems for me site.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII: codereview.SE is for improving code that actually works, not tracking down bugs.

Comment: @H2CO3, *If the given stream is of the input type, then the behavior of the function is undefined.* - from http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fflush

Comment: Are you trying to use regular expressions in `scanf`??

Comment: @chris so I thought it right, thanks.

Comment: @H2CO3 yeah using `fflush()` on an input stream is undefined and never a good idea!

Comment: @KerrekSB, From [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf), it means all but newlines are matched. See the **[set]** one.

Comment: @KerrekSB some of them actually works.

Comment: @chris: Very interesting, I never knew that one... :-)

Comment: @KerrekSB, Me neither, but I figured it was something C people use all the time, so I looked it up.

Comment: You'd be better using fgetln(stdin), btw.

Comment: Compile your code with warnings on: your bug is in line 35.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable `numberOfTracks` is a `short int`, but you are reading it with `scanf`'s `%d` specifier, which reads an `int`. This leads to undefined behavior - in this case it probably overwrites other variables such as `artist`.

Either use the `%hd` specifier (which reads a `short int`), or change the variable to an `int`.

Comment: but **numberOfTrackes** is stored correctly

Comment: It may be stored correctly on your specific machine, but there's no guarantee that will always be the case. That's the nature of undefined behavior. And even on your machine it apparently overwrites other variables.

Comment: Thanks:) @interjay 
C is difficult in the beginning :)
It's the first program

Answer (score 0):

Well, numberOfTracks is a short and you're doing a scanf("%d", &numberOfTracks) which will have interesting results.

Also, main is int main(), and you should be returning a value. The likely result of this code is that your program will terminate with a random value which happens to be closely related to the keypress from the user.